# Flutter State Management - Using Provider together with a ToggleButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I have a Toggle Button that can multi-select 2 languages [Pinyin, English]. It creates a List.

This works great, however I want to define these variables (List) globally. I intended to use the Provider Package (imported) and get it to work with a simple elevated button. However, I cannot seem to make it work with the Toggle Button that produces a List and I am unfortunately a bit lost.

My multi-select Toggle Button in my settings screen is:

```
final List<bool> _selectedLanguages = <bool>[
    true,
    true,
  ];

  List<Widget> languages = <Widget>[
    Text('Pinyin'),
    Text('English'),
  ];

ToggleButtons(
    onPressed: (int index) {
        // All buttons are selectable.
        setState(() {
        _selectedLanguages[index] =
        !_selectedLanguages[index];
        });
        print(_selectedLanguages);
    },
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(8)
    ),
    selectedBorderColor: Color(0XFF293D63),
    selectedColor: Colors.white,
    fillColor: Color(0XFF293D63),
    color: Color(0XFF293D63),
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 40.0,
        minWidth: 80.0,
    ),
    isSelected: _selectedLanguages,
    children: languages,
```

In my main.dart I have added the Multiprovidor (with ChangeNotifierProvidor) and trying to define the appropriate class below. However this is where I get lost. I cannot find a way to define the class in such a way that it can correspond with the ToggleButton in my Settings screen. Please see my code so far below:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    //// Providers are above [MyApp]
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LanguageModeModel>(
            create: (context) => LanguageModeModel()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class LanguageModeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  List<bool> indexNew = <bool>[true, true];
  void changeOutcome(newList) {
    indexNew = newList;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Any guidance on how I can make this work would be much appreciated. Thank you